# Best way to Upgrade wamp 2.0 to 2.5

Tags: wamp, upgrade

My wamp 2.0 is using around more than 100 large database and a lot of projects.I also made around more than 50 virtual host. Now I need to upgrade wamp 2.0 to 2.5.

I got some suggestion on internet that take back up of database and files , then uninstall wamp 2.0 and install 2.5 then set up every thing again, but it seems it is not a right way.

What is the best way ?

Comment: There is a HowTO on the WAMPServer Forum site [Installing a new release of WAMPServer](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Usually I follow following steps to do it easily.

1. Stop Wamp Service
2. Rename the wamp folder to wamp-backup
3. Download latest version of wamp and install it
4. Rename the data folder of mysql with some different name
   (C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20)
5. copy data folder of mysql from wamp-backup and paste it to new
   install wamp mysql folder (C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20)
6. Rename new httpd-vhosts.conf file to httpd-vhosts-backup.conf.
7. Copy old httpd-vhosts.conf and paste to new installed wamp
   (C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\extra)
8. In apache 2.4, the directive Allow was dropped in favor of new
   directive Require. So change the settings from Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all Allow from all to Require all granted

From

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
```

to

```
Require all granted
```

9.The old www folder in wamp needs to be copied into the new one.
Let me know whether it's working or not.

Comment: Thanks Vikas, It is working for me now. Specially thanks to indicate the mojor thing that is In apache 2.4, the directive Allow was dropped in favor of new directive Require

Comment: @vikas kumar how to set the directives (step no 8). i had the same problem, but can't understand it.

Comment: @adeeliqbal Step 8 is for vhost.If you want to make virtual host, then it will be used.

Comment: Also you have to uncomment the line 
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf 
in the file: 
bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf

Comment: Incase u don't understand how to do step 8, actually he just ask u to change the text in httpd-vhosts.conf at directory C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\extra

Comment: One more step. The old www folder in wamp needs to be copied into the new one.

Comment: Thanks - just used your approach to switch from Wampserver 2.4 to Wampserver 3.0 - worked beautifully. Only additional thing I had to do was to download and install the latest Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015
but that's related to the wampserver version and not to your answer. Anyway - thanks again!

Comment: Ok a word of warning - don't copy the mysql data folder. Instead, copy the entire mysql.x.y.z folder into C:\wamp\bin\mysql and then you'll have the option to switch to the old version of mysql from within the wamp manager. At first it appeared that everything is working for me but it turned out copying just the data from one msql version to another is a recipe for disaster. I ended up with a corrupt mysq.user table and a whole lot of related PITA issues. So instead I just copied the entire mysql version to the new wamp server and now everything works beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

you should do this , I recently updated it , first of all I took my Wamp directory back, then uninstall Wamp not remove the www directory , After that install the latest wamp on the same location , after this copy the folder named `data` inside the old `wamp` `bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24`  and paste that folder inside your new wamp on the same location  then run your projects after starting the wamp services.

**Note: folder version of db may be different and also latest wamp is based on virtual host so create v hosts also**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may **directly** *Upgrade Wampserver* from [Secondary repository of Wampserver files](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en).

There are various options present on the site:

1. Install Wampserver full version
2. Wampserver Update
3. Addons-

   - Applications
   - Apache
   - PHP
   - MySQL
   - MariaDB

Also, one could directly download Tools and Visual C++ packages from here.

So, my suggestion would **not** be to make any changes in any file in the wamp, nor uninstall the present wamp, and download the latest version. Simply update your wampserver from this website.

> There will be no change to the Apache, PHP, MySQL, and MariaDB
>   settings and versions used; your local sites and databases will not be
>   affected. This update will be necessary to be able to install the last
>   addons Apache, PHP, MySQL or MariaDB

*Quoted from the site itself.*

**NOTE:** Before uptading, you may just make a copy/backup of your "wamp folder" somewhere on your local machine. In case there is some issue in the update, you won't lose any file and always be able to restore your previous work.

Hope this answer helps someone, if it does kindly upvote. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

To update to latest wamp version safely, use http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/
You can update complete wamp or install newer php/apache versions.